# Difference between Sitecore solr index rebuild and refresh

Tags: indexing, solr, sitecore, sitecore7.2

we would like to know what is the difference between `Sitecore full index rebuild` and `index refresh`. When we want to refresh item in index it took ~2 min. Full rebuild of master index took ~10min. Why index refresh is so time consuming?

We are refreshing item using this code:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Item item = GetItem();
var masterIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index");
masterIndex.Refresh(new SitecoreIndexableItem(item));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh"? Do you just mean add new version of the selected item to the index? How do you execute this "refresh"?

Comment: I've edited task, adding code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm looking in the decompiled source of the Sitecore.ContentSearch assembly and it looks like the `Refresh` method eventually calls the `RefreshTree` method on the `IndexCustodian` class. The `RefreshTree` will create a new object array for the item to be indexed and will then iterate through all the available indices (even though you've called it from a specific index) and creating a refresh job for each of them (which are added to a queue for processing):

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Job> RefreshTree(IIndexable startItem)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(startItem, "startItem");
    CrawlingLog.Log.Debug(string.Format("IndexCustodian. RefreshTree triggered on item {0}.", startItem.AbsolutePath), null);
    return 
        from index in ContentSearchManager.Indexes
        select IndexCustodian.Refresh(index, startItem);
}

public static Job Refresh(ISearchIndex index, IIndexable indexable)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(index, "index");
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(indexable, "indexable");
    object[] objArray = new object[] { indexable };
    JobOptions jobOptions = IndexCustodian.GetJobOptions(index, "Refresh", objArray, true);
    jobOptions.CustomData = indexable;
    CrawlingLog.Log.Debug(string.Format("IndexCustodian. Refresh triggered on index {0}. Data={1}", index.Name, jobOptions.CustomData), null);
    return JobManager.Start(jobOptions);
}
```

The `FullRebuild` method (also in `IndexCustodian`) calls the `CreateRebuildJob` which direcly creates one job to be processed:

```cs
public static Job FullRebuild(ISearchIndex index, bool start = true)
    {
        return IndexCustodian.CreateRebuildJob(index, new EventHandler<JobStartedEventArgs>(IndexCustodian.RebuildStartedHandler), new EventHandler<JobFinishedEventArgs>(IndexCustodian.RebuildFinishedHandler), start, null);
    }

private static Job CreateRebuildJob(ISearchIndex index, EventHandler<JobStartedEventArgs> startedHandler = null, EventHandler<JobFinishedEventArgs> finishedHandler = null, bool start = true, object[] parameters = null)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(index, "index");
        JobOptions jobOptions = IndexCustodian.GetJobOptions(index, "Rebuild", parameters, false);
        Job job = new Job(jobOptions);
        if (startedHandler != null)
        {
            job.Started += startedHandler;
        }
        if (finishedHandler != null)
        {
            job.Finished += finishedHandler;
        }
        if (start)
        {
            CrawlingLog.Log.Warn(string.Format("IndexCustodian. FullRebuild triggered on index {0}.", index.Name), null);
            JobManager.Start(job);
        }
        return job;
    }
```

So the `Refresh` method has some overhead by iterating through indices and then is dependent on the `JobManager` for queuing and processing the refresh jobs (multiple if several indices have been found).

Comment: That doesn't explain why refresh is quicker than rebuild.

Comment: @JanBühler Refresh starts the indexing from a particular startItem path whereas Rebuild does it for the entire tree. So even though, Refresh will check if the specified item path (and its descendants) are in multiple indexes and then reindex all of them, it will only do it for those items whereas Rebuild will index the entire tree albeit only 1 index.